# How to Change URL With JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If a person came to my site, they will find multiple instances of following URL in a hyperlink:

> https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId=%7B6DDF7ABCX%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&ID=14

I want to use JavaScript to replace the above URL on load to the below.

> https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/Item/editifs.aspx?ID=14&Source=https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/AO12.aspx&DefaultView=AO

The ID can change depending on the ID of the item. How can I replace the URL and preserve the ID in the new URLs?

I tried finding a tutorial and came up with the below, but no luck

```
<script>
var ourInterestingString = “https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&amp;ListId=%7B6DDF7ABCX%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&amp;ID=14”;
var ourNewString = ourInterestingString
    .replace(“https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&amp;ListId=%7B6DDF7ABCX%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&amp;”, “https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/Item/editifs.aspx?”)

console.log(ourNewString);</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse the URL with [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

```js
const old_url = "https://example.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId=%7B6DDF7ABCX%2D5A27%2D4BEB%2DB4F9%2D158FAA3F0B34%7D&ID=14";

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(old_url);
const ID = searchParams.get("ID");

const new_url = `https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/Item/editifs.aspx?ID=${ID}&Source=https://example.com/Lists/Your%20Col/AO12.aspx&DefaultView=AO`;

console.log(new_url);
```

Comment: thank you, but this is not working for me.  I tried putting the code on the page I need it on, but all of the URLs are still the same